# Please help. I do not understand this solution. Linear independence.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\{f_a : (0,1)\rightarrow R | f_a(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-ax}\}_{a\in(0,1)}$ is linearly independent.

Here is the solution from the textbook:

Let n is a positive integer. Suppose $a_1,\dots,a_n \in (0,1)$ and $ a_i\ne a_j (i\ne j)$ that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i f_i=0, \quad \forall x\in(0,1)$

$\forall x \in (0,1): \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\lambda_i}{1-a_ix}=0$
=>$\forall x \in (0,1): \lambda_i=-(1-a_ix)\sum\limits_{1\geq j \leq n (i\ne j)}\dfrac{\lambda_j}{1-a_jx}$.

Let x approach $\dfrac{1}{a_i}$ then $\lambda_i=0$

My question is: since $x\in (0,1)$ so does it make sense to make x tend to $\dfrac{1}{a_i}>1$ ? If it does not work, please show me how to solve this problem. Thank you !

Comment: In your proof, you should let $x$ approach $0$ instead of $\frac{1}{a_i}$. Your sum will approach the sum of $\lambda_i$ which is nonzero if at least one $\lambda_i \neq 0$.

But you can't let $x$ approach $\frac{1}{a_i}$ since it is not in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @djvyu72 Thank you for your comment but it does not look right to me. By letting x approach 0, we're gonna get $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n=0$ which cannot imply $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$. For instance, i can chose $\lambda_1=-\lambda_2=1$.

Comment: @Bungu You are right, I need to think more about this problem, sorry for the mistake. Should you also have $\lambda_j x$ instead of $\lambda_j$ alone on your equation?

Comment: @djvyu72 Why $\lambda_j x instead of \lambda_j$ ? There is no more x since we let x goes to 0, only constant $\lambda_j$ left

Comment: @Bungu What I don't understand is that on the statement of the question, $f_a =\frac{x}{1-ax}$ but when you pass to the summ you have $\sum \frac{\lambda_i}{1-a_ix},$ instead of $\sum \frac{\lambda_i x}{1-a_ix}.$ Which one is your function?

Comment: @djvyu72 Oh, i'm very sory. My mistake. $f_a=\dfrac{1}{1-ax}$. I have just recorrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Let n is a positive integer. Suppose $a_1,\dots,a_n \in (0,1)$ and $ a_i\ne a_j (i\ne j)$ that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i f_i=0, \quad \forall x\in(0,1)$

Now, choose  $x_1,\dots,x_n \in (0,1)$ and $ x_i = a_i $. The equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i f_i=0, \; \forall x_j $ will give you the folowing matrix equation,
$$\mathbf{A}\vec{\lambda} = 0,\quad A_{ij} = \frac{1}{1-a_ia_j}$$

Since 
$$\det A= \frac{\prod_{{\substack{
   i,j \\
   i<j
  }}}(a_i-a_j)^2}{\prod_{{\substack{
   i,j \\
   i\leq j
  }}}(a_ia_j-1)^2} \neq 0$$

You can conclude that $\vec{\lambda} =0, \forall n$.

*(Note, to find the determinant, you can use induction as in the proof of [cauchy determinant](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant).
If you accept the formula of Cauchy Determinant, the matrix $A_{ij} = \frac{\frac{1}{a_i}}{\frac{1}{a_i}-a_j}$ is very close to the Cauchy Matrix. When calculating $\det A$, you can factor out $\frac{1}{a_i}$ from the numerator in each column and what's left is exactly a Cauchy Determinant.)*

Comment: Thank you very much. It's definitely a very good solution for this problem. But could you get the idea of the solution that i wrote ? I think it's  incorrect since some typing errors i guess. But what i really concern here is the idea of using limit in proving a set of function is linearly independent.

Comment: Your doubt is definitely correct. The limit it takes is invalid since that's outside the domain of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make induction on $n$; the base case is clear because those functions are nonzero.

So assume
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\lambda_if_{a_i}(x)=0
$$
If $\lambda_{n+1}=0$, we're done; so it's not restrictive to assume $\lambda_{n+1}=-1$, so that
$$
\frac{1}{1-a_{n+1}x}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i}{1-a_ix}
$$
Multiply both sides by $1-a_{n+1}x$, so
$$
1=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i(1-a_{n+1}x)}{1-a_ix}
$$
This is an equality between rational functions that is satisfied for all $x\in(0,1)$. Let $P(x)=(1-a_1x)(1-a_2x)\dots(1-a_nx)$, so we have
$$
P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(1-a_{n+1}x)P_i(x)
$$
where $P_i(x)=P(x)/(1-a_i(x))$ is a polynomial.

Since this equality is satisfied by infinitely many values of $x$ the two polynomials are equal. But the roots of $P$ are $1/a_1,1/a_2,\dots,1/a_n$, while the right hand side has $1/a_{n+1}$ as root. This is a contradiction.

---

The method used in your textbook would require some more words: the function you're using is the restriction of a continuous function defined on a larger set (where $x\ne a_i^{-1}$), so it's legitimate to draw conclusions on the restriction from the behavior of the “more general” function.

The algebraic method I used is based on the same idea, it just doesn't require limits.

Comment: thank you. It seems to me that we cannot use limit in this case. I thought my solution above was just wrong because of some typing errors of the textbook.

Comment: @Bungbu You *can* use limits: those functions are restrictions of functions defined on larger sets, so it's legitimate to draw conclusions on the restrictions from the behavior of the “more general” functions. The method I used is based on the same idea, but requires no limit.

Comment: I don't get that. How is it legitimate to draw conclusions on the restrictions from the behavior of the more general function ? For instance i choose $f(x)=1-x^2$ and the restriction is on the interval (-1,1). $f(x)>0$ with the restriction but $f(3)<0$.  I would appreciate if you could explain your idea more in detail.

Comment: @Bungbu I can only repeat myself: those functions *are* restrictions of rational functions defined on the reals (except a finite number of points). The fact that you are considering them in the interval $(0,1)$ doesn't cancel this.